# How to use R for infering on a dicotomic variable depending on two independent variables?

Tags: r

I've a problem concerning a data-set, but I am a newbe in the field of data analysis so I need your help in finding a good solution.

My data-set is composed by just 3 columns:
"x" is a vector of success/failure (1 or 0) while "y" and "z" are both vectors of integers.

I would love to find a "formal" way to state something like
"When the couple (y,z) belong to the 2D interval AxB, then the variable "x" is a success with 95% of probability".

I specify that for the moment I am using R.

Comment: Can you please elaborate by giving a few sample rows of your dataframe and desired output in respect of that dataframe

Comment: Logistic regression is a topic that you will probably find is applicable to your problem.